# Wordpress Multisite - This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, redirect, loops

I had installed a Wordpress Multisite on my localhost, it works ok but when I put it on server and changed all URL stuffs on DB I got this error: **Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects**.

Someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Try locating where the problem is by deactivating plugins one by one and switching to a well tested theme such as Twenty Eleven.

Comment: I don't know exactly what was the problem, but I was trying to upload to http://www.mydomain.com/new and it was triggering that error then I uploaded to http://new.mydomain.com and I didn't had the problem anymore..

Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your .htaccess file.

If you have activated multisite, then go to your networg settings
and copy your  .htacces code generated by wordpress.

Paste the code  in  .htaccess  and update file on server.

Finally refresh you dasboard and try it!

Tell me it it's work!